# Large PostgreSQL table: better to add a column or create a new table to store metadata?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, database-design

I have a large table (~2 million rows), each row of which represents one image. I want to store the EXIF metadata in JSON format for each image. This JSON blob is about 6KB per image.

This EXIF metadata won't be queried/used very often, and I'm wondering whether it'd be significantly more efficient to store it in a separate table with two columns (imageid, exifjson), or whether PostgreSQL will deal with this just fine as a `text` column on existing table. I wouldn't want adding the column to significantly slow down ordinary queries on the table, or the millions of 6KB text values to bog PostgreSQL down.

Comment: If the rest of the rows is smaller than the 6K for the blobs, then putting the exif-blobs in a separate table will make the footprint of the "working set" for typical queries (not using the exif) considerably smaller, which means you make better use of your buffer space. (instead of flooding it with stuff you don't need)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would make that column [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html)-ed.

```
 ALTER TABLE ... ALTER <column> SET STORAGE <EXTERNAL|EXTENDED>;
 -- EXTERNAL - out-of-line storage, not compression[1]
 -- EXTENDED - both compression and out-of-line storage
```

PostgreSQL already try to use it for data larger than ~2kB.

[1] "The compression technique used is a fairly simple and very fast member of the LZ family of compression techniques."

Answer (score 3):

Better to use separate table, but you will be ok with existing table. You'll scarcely get a impact unless you retrieve this field using existing "select * from" queries. And you'll never fill postgres up with such data since it has almost infinite thresholds:

- Maximum Database Size    Unlimited
- Maximum Table Size   32 TB
- Maximum Row Size 1.6 TB
- Maximum Field Size   1 GB
- Maximum Rows per Table   Unlimited
- Maximum Columns per Table    250 - 1600 depending on column types
- Maximum Indexes per Table    Unlimited

http://www.postgresql.org/about/

About interfering during selection of other column data:

> Very long values are also stored in background tables so that they do not interfere with rapid access to shorter column values.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html

Comment: Thanks. That sounds about right, but do you have any references to back it up?